# Drawing ellipsis between nodes in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I'm interested in drawing vertical ellipsis between nodes in graphviz like seen below:
[image]

The problem I'm having is whenever I try to do this I cannot seem to get `x3` and `xn` to line up vertically as seen here:
[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
digraph G {
rankdir=LR
splines=line

subgraph cluster_0 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid, color=black, shape=circle];
    x1 x2 x3 xn [group=g1];
    label = "Input Features";
}

subgraph cluster_1 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid, color=red2, shape=circle];
    a1 [group=g2];
    label = "Activation";
}

subgraph cluster_2 {
    color=white;
    node [style=solid, color=green, shape=circle];
    out [group=g3];
    label = "Output";
}

x1 -> a1;
x2 -> a1;
x3 -> a1;
a1 -> out;
x3 -> xn [arrowhead="none", color="black:invis:black"];
}
```

I'm very new to graphviz so I'm not even sure if I'm using subgraph properly here. I also tried adding the nodes in the subgraphs to groups, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Is your question about how to add ellipsis or how to vertically lineup nodes? I'm asking you because I googled the title of your question and the bellows answer is not exactly related to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
{ rank = same; x1 x2 x3 xn }
x1 -> x2 -> x3[ style = invis ];
```

to your first subgraph. This has the effect that

- the four nodes are all one one level, i.e. lining up vertically
- the three numbered nodes stay together

Here my version:

```
digraph G 
{
    rankdir = LR
    splines = line

    subgraph cluster_0 
    {
        color = white;
        node[ style = solid, color = black, shape = circle];
        { rank = same; x1 x2 x3 xn }
        x1 -> x2 -> x3[ style = invis ];
        label = "Input Features";
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 
    {
        color = white;
        node[ style = solid, color = red2, shape = circle ];
        a1;
        label = "Activation";
    }

    subgraph cluster_2 
    {
        color =white;
        node[ style = solid, color = green, shape = circle ];
        out;
        label = "Output";
    }

    x1 -> a1;
    x2 -> a1;
    x3 -> a1;
    a1 -> out;
    x3 -> xn[ arrowhead = "none", color = "black:invis:black" ];
}
```

which gives you

[image]

---

E D I T   to answer the question in your comment; the key is reversing the order of node definitions and edge direction within the same rank, probably caused by the `rankdir = LR` layout. After all, there is a simple solution!

```
digraph G 
{
    rankdir = LR
    splines = line

    subgraph cluster_0 
    {
        color = white;
        label = "Input Features";
        node[ style = solid, color = black, shape = circle ];

        /* define and connect in reverse order */
        { rank = same; xn x3 x2 x1 }
        x3 -> x2 -> x1[ style = invis ];
        xn -> x3[ arrowhead = "none", color = "black:invis:black" ];
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 
    {
        color = white;
        node[ style = solid, color = red2, shape = circle ];
        a1;
        label = "Activation";
    }

    subgraph cluster_2 
    {
        color =white;
        node[ style = solid, color = green, shape = circle ];
        out;
        label = "Output";
    }

    { x1 x2 x3 } -> a1;
    a1 -> out;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to force `x1` to start at the top and go downwards to `xn` for `cluster_0`?